# file read/write Popen python

Tags: python, python-3.x, popen

I'm trying to Read/Write process file with command `grep` and `cut` to get part of the IP address using pipe operator, here is the process simply written.

```
import subprocess as sub
import shlex

    def discover_Host():    
     with open("Get_IP.txt", "w+") as q_process:
       cmd1 = "grep Host xmap_ip.gnmap"
       cmd2 = "cut -d ' ' -f 2"
       arg1 = shlex.split(cmd1)
       arg2 = shlex.split(cmd2)
    
       proc1 = sub.Popen(args1, stdout = sub.PIPE)
       proc2 = sub.Popen(args2, stdin = proc1.stdout, stdout = q_process)
    
       proc1.stdout.close()
       out, err = proc2.communicate()
    return
```

Now the file `Get_IP.txt` contains data like this `Host: 172:22:179:156 (abc.efg.net) Status: Up` so I'm trying to get only IP address from it as I run the **grep** and **cut** command with **pipe** directly on the terminal it works but as I try it with **SubProcess** it doesn't write on the file.

Comment: pass `shell=True` to `sub.Popen`

Comment: Why are you using `grep` and `cut` when Python has a built-in operations for this?

Comment: @ahmed That's not needed, he used `shlex.split()` to split it into a list.

Comment: What was the point of `proc1.stdout.close()`?  proc1 probably hasn't finished (or perhaps even *started* yet) at that point in time.

Comment: @ahmed why? that shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to use shell commands for this, it can be done entirely in Python.

```
def discover_Host():
    with open('xmap_ip.gnmap') as xmap, open("Get_IP.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for line in xmap:
            if 'Host' in line:
                field2 = line.split(' ')[1]
                print(field2, file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine both commands in one call, but you must pass `shell` to `sub.Popen`:

```
   cmd1 = "grep Host xmap_ip.gnmap | cut -d ' ' -f 2"
   proc1 = sub.Popen(cmd1, shell=True)
```

Comment: strange your command does work for `echo 'hello world'` and writes on the file but for `grep Host xmap_ip.gnmap | cut -d ' ' -f 2` it does not write and I assume it does not read as well.

Comment: found out the root cause it was due to method being called synchronously which created the file `xmap_ip.gnmap` and was trying to attempt and read the line using `grep` so in order to halt the process I used the `proc0.wait()` on first method before calling the `cmd1 = "grep Host xmap_ip.gnmap | cut -d ' ' -f 2"` second method.